# How to fix 'Cannot resolve AutoValue_MyClass' in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Regarding AutoValue defined here:

https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/builders.md

In IntelliJ, when I create a basic class using AutoValue,

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
  public static Builder builder()
  {
    return new AutoValue_MyClass.Builder();
  }
  ...
}
```

I get "Cannot resolve symbol  '**`AutoValue_MyClass`**'"?

Is there some way to fix this?  A plugin perhaps?

I have Annotations enabled and an AutoValue plugin that helps generate AutoValue classes, but nothing seems to help resolve the AutoValue_* prefix

Comment: What is this class `AutoValue_MyClass`? You declare it?

Comment: https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md

Comment: You will have to explain what tool or plugin you are using for AutoValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoValue generates source code. You can tell IJ to add that source code to your project, by simply clicking right on it in the project explorer, selecting 'directory', and marking it as source.

Comment: In my case, AutoValue classes were being generated in a subdir called `target/generated-sources/annotations`. All I did was go to `File > Project Structure > Modules` and marked the aforementioned dir as a Source Folder, and IDEA immediately found the AutoValue classes.